# Optimize redundant CSS styles in HTML

Tags: css, optimization, lib

Our loading crew is using different WYSIWYG HTML editors to prepare an offers. Unofrtunatelly the result code is usually not optimized and it demands a lot of space in our db.

Example codes:

```
<ul style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
    <li><span style="font-size: 10pt;">qwe</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-size: 10pt;">asd</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-size: 10pt;">zxc</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-size: 10pt;">qwer</span></li>
    <li><span style="font-size: 10pt;">asdf</span></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">lorem</span>
<div style="font-size: 13.3333px;"><br></div>
<div style="font-size: 13.3333px;">ipsum</div>
```

is there any useful lib/script which can optimize those styles before saving it to db?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it's the inline styles that you'd like to get rid of. There's an online tool called HTML cleaner that can do this for you: [HTML Cleaner Remove Inline Styles](https://html-cleaner.com/features/remove-html-inline-styles/).

Comment: And just as a thought, rather than doing this yourself, could educating your loading crew work?

Comment: It's not a matter of education, an WYSIWYG HTML editor is a graphical editor to generate HTML.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Winter. But I was thinking the loading crew could run the code their WYSIWYG editors generates through an HTML cleaner, before they submit it. Maybe a small extra step for them?

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to get rid off all the styles. I want to remove redundant ones, as I stated in the title. I've checked html-cleaner.com but unfortnatelly it's removing *all* the inline styling.